# In-wall tube for running cables between brush-style wall plates?

Tags: wiring

I'm setting up some [brush-style cable entry wall plates](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00OB21EDU) in a short vertical in-wall space between where my TV and a floating console are mounted in my home.

It would be easy to fish some cables while I'm actually setting this up, but I don't have any right now. I want to make the process as simple as possible in the future.

Is there some sort of tube or conduit-like thing that I can run (and easily terminate into that brush-style cable entry wall plate) between these two points? I have some leftover flexible liquid-tight PVC conduit from another job that might be suitable, though I'm not sure how I'd terminate it.

Note: this is only for low-voltage cables. I'm also running NM to a separate properly installed old-work box, but that's out-of-scope for this question.

Comment: With low voltage cables, the conduit/tube type does not matter if it works.  That plate seems to be more of a faceplate(no back shown) and does not have any type of connection spot(you push cables though).  A fixed conduit bend to the back should allow cables to pass though.

Comment: @crip659 I have a low voltage bracket holding it to the wall. How would I terminate the fixed conduit bend to that?

Comment: Would need a box to fix conduit to.  Without a box, having the conduit end fixed to the wall/stud very close to the opening, could probably pull the cables though the opening with fingers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Smurf tube (ENT) is the usual obvious choice. Orange less-smurfy tube if you can easily find it, but blue is fine.

If you have leftover liquidtight you can use it, and I won't tell you to run screaming as it's apparently a short enough run that its status as the most miserable type of conduit to pull cable into (in my experience) will probably not apply. You terminate it with liquidtight fittings, of course. It's a system, whether or not you actually need liquid-tight-ness. You can get LV wall rings that have a hole to connect conduits to, or you can put an actual box beind the wall plate.

Comment: There are also widgets sold for the purpose, and/or 3d printable, which are basically two sections that enter from opposite sides of the wall and attach in the middle. I've used one (branded as "wall eye" and was happy with it. But that was for a simple straight-line penetration.

Comment: If you don’t want to buy 25’ of smurf tube, plain old drainage hose comes in more reasonable lengths, and usually cheaper. A few zip ties can usually connect it adequately to your low voltage jbox.

Comment: Do you have any examples of the "LV wall rings that have a hole to connect conduits to"? A quick search didn't turn up much. I currently have a basic LV bracket that I've attached the wall plate to.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate great idea with the zip ties!

Comment: @keshlam I looked up wall eye and they look like they only cover the cable in the half inch or so of drywall, but they don't seem to do anything inside the wall. I already have a way of getting the cables inside the drywall (that brush wall plate) but need some sort of tube to make pulling new cables easy in the future. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Yep, you're misunderanding. Each piece has a tube, with threads so they interlock inside the wall. Only works for straight-through, admittedly, but that's all I needed; once through I'm using surface guides to go up the corner of the room and fan out along the ceiling edges.